# Clarification - Code of Conduct - Sensitive content and questions

Tags: support, etiquette, code-of-conduct

The section "Sensitive content and imagery policy" of the Code of Conduct available on [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct/sensitive-content) states that the network does not allow some types of ***content*** or imagery including

> Sexually Explicit Material – material that is explicitly sexual, pornographic, prurient, or lascivious in nature.

I am asking for clarifications on this policy. Does this mean that questions about adult related material are forbidden by the CoC itself and therefore ***EVERY*** site has to comply, no matter what the "local culture" may be?

For full context, I am asking this because on [Anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) every now and then some smart guy feels the urge to ask quite explicit questions to try to identify some NSFW material they saw somewhere, often going in great detail to "write a good identification question". Then some fast finger user migrates those to [Sci-Fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). See an example [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281128/im-looking-for-a-manga), if you really have to.
Since both chat rooms have new question alert bots, those are also shared to whoever is in the chat at that time. And obviously the one box includes the text of the question, if the title was not already explicit enough.

I am starting to get quite annoyed by this... So I would kindly request the company to clarify if the CoC does indeed offer the opportunity to start a nice witch hunt and burn some of this content.

(Notice: obviously this is NOT about legitimate questions that could for example appear on a medical site.)

Comment: This is also a question I asked somewhere before but without a good answer. Some of these questions are asking for the identification of illustrated child pornography (or CSAM). While the questions don't contain any links/images (and a potential answer might not either), illustrated child porn is illegal in the US and itself against the CoC. But because there's no actual images/links in the posts I'm unsure what should be done with it.

Comment: If the questions are unwanted on both sites, the old saying of "don't migrate crap" seems to apply.

Answer (score 11):

Provided they remain academic in tone, and gate sensitive material behind spoiler markup, my understanding is that these are allowed. These questions are usually well-received (e.g. [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145167/58038), [2](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6527/1411), [3](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/818)), and it would be a shame to “burn” them.

The question you've linked is *not* a high-quality question: I don't think we should be deciding policies around the worst examples. I think it would be appropriate to have higher quality-control standards for such questions (including expedited deletion of the worst examples), but this is a question of site-specific moderation policy and unrelated to the Code of Conduct.

---

> This is also a question I asked somewhere before but without a good answer. Some of these questions are asking for the identification of illustrated child pornography (or CSAM). […] — [Laurel](/users/323179/laurel) [2023-11-23 17:51:00Z](/posts/comments/1320271)

Excellent point: I really don't think depictions of CSAM should be treated the same *at all*. It irks me how often they're lumped in together.

In rare cases, I imagine such works *might* have historical or cultural significance, and we should be allowed Q&A about them. Think works of classical Greek art, or particularly-notable *Edo*-period *shunga*.

But in what I expect would be the majority of cases (I *do* know the demographics of the internet), these questions are about recent works with no merit beyond the prurient. I see no reason to help document such material, if it's sexualising children (or 3000-year-old sparkly vampires, whatever).

It's *pretty* easy to tell the difference between significant and prurient works, from how the identification requests are written. (Or, at least, between curiosity and prurient interest of the querent, which is a good enough heuristic in my book.)

---

> Since both chat rooms have new question alert bots, those are also shared to whoever is in the chat at that time. And obviously the one box includes the text of the question if the title was not already explicit enough.

Spoilered text [does not appear in chat oneboxes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64756158#64756158), and there's a delay before new questions end up posted by the feed bot. If you're quick enough with your edits, you can catch these posts before they get posted to chat.

If you don't want to participate in moderation, [you can mute](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#mute) those feed bots and never have to see *any* question that fails muster. If you do, and something's particularly objectionable, you can flag the chat message as spam/offensive; then, at least, it won't bother future readers of the transcript.

> I am starting to get quite annoyed by this...

Though you are years my senior: welcome, once again, to moderation! I am so, so sorry.

Comment: I generally agree with your main point, the issue is that your proposed solution is still opt-in. It requires the user to act in order to be protected, while any actual good system would need to do the opposite.

Comment: Ideally, you would have a "sensitive content" flag you could check on a question (and some heuristic that suggest it when appropriate) and a corresponding "show sensitive content" option in your user profile. This option should also be disabled for anyone whose declared age is under 18 years old.

Comment: @SPArcheon “Sensitive content” is far too broad and vague. In practice, it tends to line up with the norms of a certain US subculture, and has a chilling effect on any other kind of expression. Like, how would you tag [this Skeptics question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/44479/32519)?

Comment: It starts off with the best of intentions, but invariably you end up participating in a project of cultural imperialism (ref: Reddit, Tumblr, Instagram), or somebody else takes the reigns and then all that machinery you've built is turned towards evil (ref: Twitter). We can decide how to categorise things, and declare things on- or off-topic, but (except for genuinely harmful stuff, like abusive or exploitative material) we can't decide what is sensitive or not: that is and should remain subjective.

Comment: That's not even getting into the additional data collection required for age-gating – and how would it interact with logged-out users? Would things get login-gated? Would this age-gating then open SE up to liability under the myriad of poorly-considered laws designed for the likes of Facebook and YouTube (with a grudging exception for Wikipedia, that Stack Exchange cannot employ because it is not a charitable foundation)? Stack Exchange might not be "safe for children", but it is perfectly suitable for real-world children (once the first pass of moderation has occurred, at least).

Comment: I think that the example I made in my post if far different from yours. Your is someone asking for a confirmation that something happened (and that something coincidentally is NSFW). The question I linked is someone using the site to find NSFW material.

Comment: @SPArcheon The entire category of “NSFW” _only exists_ [within certain cultures](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/204032) – and wherever it's been exported, via the internet. I've been interacting with the concept for a third of my life, and I still don't get where the boundaries are supposed to be – it _certainly_ doesn't line up with the inclusion criteria for my school's library, for instance. I don't think it's a suitable concept for an international site.

Answer (score 6):

I think "adult related material" is too vague of a description to be able to say anything meaningful about with regards to the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) (which is valid network-wide: "*It applies to everyone using Meta Stack Exchange and the Stack Exchange network*").

Your example, however, can be regarded as being in violation of the CoC: the author of that post mentions it is [hentai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hentai) they are looking for, which by its very nature is pornographic. I think it can be closed for that reason.

It can also be flagged as being

> **Rude or abusive**
> A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.

And then it might be closed for being distasteful (but in this case my flag was denied).

But this is a blurry area, and interpretations of the clauses can vary between sites. What if the author didn't mention it was hentai, specifically? What if they pointed out it was, say, part of a series of manga that explores Freudian concepts? Especially where it concerns 'art' or craft, I think **this has to be judged on a case-by-case basis**.

Comment: The whole point is exactly that. I want an official statement from the staff that states that questions about "Sexually Explicit Material" as the CoC calls it are forbidden or gives guidance about how to handle this. Part of the issue is that multiple places on the site will show you the text of a question without you asking for it. Therefore, even if the title of the question was "fine" viewing the actual content often is not an opt-in choice.

Comment: @SPArcheon So your main concern is that it should not appear on the sites to begin with? It seems to me that words like 'hentai' and for specific body parts could easily be blocked on certain sites when writing a Q/A/C. That could be a good start.

Comment: Much simpler: what I meant is that even if someone claimed that you are free to not read such question and those topics being "opt-in" that is simply not true because the site shows them in your face anyway and you have to "opt-out" instead, taking personal actions to hide them.

Comment: @SPArcheon In all other cases, to the extent it _is_ handled, that's handled using the tagging system. I don't understand why this is different. (We don't have a way of filtering out questions about incredibly violent material, for example; rather than censoring, I'd rather we implemented a proper content warning system of some kind.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yet tagging is still opt-out: you would have to manually ignore the tags you don't want to see, and hope users use them consistently. And even then, I think some areas of the site would ignore that (for example, a new question feed posted to a chatroom)

Comment: @SPArcheon True. I probably should have asked for a built-in content warning system when I first thought about it, so it could have been prioritised. We can probably make something ourselves, though, like how duplicates weren't built in originally (being closure + an appropriately-formatted blockquote) – all it'd need is for spoiler markup to be made a first-class Markdown extension.